# Deleting element from ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to copy 'select' elements from hands[1] to hands[0].
I can successfully do this with this code:

```
       for(Card card : hands[1].cards) {
          if (card.suit().ordinal() == 0){
             hands[0].addSingleCard(card);
             //hands[1].removeSingleCard(card);
             }
       }
```

Unfortunately, my removeSingleCard method doesn't work how i expected. 
With it commented out, the for-each loop successfully copies all 'Club' cards from hands[1] to hands[0]. I was hoping the removeSingleCard method would delete each 'Club' card from hands[1] after it was copied.

```
       public void addSingleCard(Card card){
           if(card!= null){
             cards.add(card);
           }
       }

       public void removeSingleCard(Card c){
           if(c!= null){
             cards.remove(c);
           }
       }
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Comment: The `card.suit().ordinal() == 0` test is unidiomatic.  Just use `card.suit() == Suit.CLUBS`.  If you defined your suits in a different order, use the 0th element in the enum.  Any use of `Enum.ordinal()` should arouse suspicion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't remove from a collection you're iterating over, other than *via* the iterator. So you could use:

```
for (Iterator<Card> iterator = hands[1].cards.iterator();
     iterator.hasNext(); ) {
    Card card = iterator.next();
    if (card.suit().ordinal() == 0) {
        hands[0].addSingleCard(card); // Or hands[0].cards.add(card);
        iterator.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah nice :) This is awesome. Its exactly what i was trying to achieve. Thanks so much. I definitely need to remember this :D

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you get a `ConcurrentModificationException` since you are removing from a collection while you are iterating in the `for` loop.
You should use `iterator.remove`